# I can't get the corner points of chessboard by cv2.cornerSubPix()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, corner-detection

I have a chessboard and I want to calibrate my camera attached to a telecentric lens using it. But I can't get the corner points at sub-pixel accuracy with OpenCV's cv.cornerSubPix() command. When I run it, it gives no results. Then when I crop the image and enter the appropriate square number, I get the same result, nothing changes! It gives me an empty list of corner pixels. Can you help me?

You can access original images here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XmjOvUFBop7Fxzrjo-_7MawiDI-b0GxF?usp=share_link

[image]

[image]

Comment: misunderstanding. cornersubpix ***refines*** corners, it doesn't find them. please consult the documentation.